# Команда для linux в автозапуск

Tags: linux, администрирование

Ребят как сделать так чтобы при старте операционки(Linux) стартовала команда

```
/etc/init.d/sysklogd restart
```

потому что опытным путём выяснил что через reboot он не рестартится. Это нужно для пересылки логов об аутентификации на другой сервер - верный или неверный ввод пароля.

Comment: python не прокатит, у заказчика требование только с++

Comment: @НиколаКривошея нет никакой разницы, на каком языке написано то, что запускают перечисленные рецепты.

Comment: Какой дистибутив? В последних версиях ubuntu из-за systemd надо несколько иные действия выполнять

Comment: Рестарт демона при загрузке - сильно. Почему вы думаете, что когда старт не проходит - рестарт в то же самое время чем-то поможет? Надо чинить запуск демона, а не крутить костыли.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно выполнить пару команд

```
update-rc.d sysklogd defaults #не для всех дистрибутивов
update-rc.d sysklogd enable
```

Если скрипт совместимый с дистром. Для системд с пакетом совместимости  и апстарт ссылка на запуск тоже обновится.

Answer (score 2):

В дистрибутивах Linux за авто-выполнение команд отвечает файл "rc.local", который расположен по пути: /etc/rc.local

1.Открываем файл rc.local

2.Вставляем комманду до строки exit 0

Comment: посмотри на /etc/init.d/skeleton - там интересно

Answer (score 1):

```
rc-update add sysklogd default
```